# Does SAT work for testing intersection of convex 2d shape with convex 3d shape

Tags: geometry

Does the [separating axis theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperplane_separation_theorem) work for testing intersection between a convex 3d shape and a convex 2d shape that exists in the same 3d space?

Comment: A convex 2d shape in 3d is in particular a convex subset of $R^3$, so there is a separating plane.

Answer (score 3):

The basic answer is yes.

SAT works as follows:

[image]

If the two shapes are convex and non-intersecting, then there is at least one point on a bounding circle such that when rays are projected from it, there are two non-overlapping shadows (shown in orange). If the two shapes are intersecting, then the two shadows always overlap.

There is a write-up of some of the algorithms at [dyn4j](http://www.dyn4j.org/2010/01/sat/).

In $3$ dimensions we need to use a bounding sphere. Objects of a lesser dimension can be treated as $3D$ objects with a height (and length for $1D$ objects) of $1$ pixel.